# owl:equivalentProperty relations between DBPedia and Yago

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, linked-data

Is there any graph that contains mappings between equivalent properties in DBPedia and Yago? My application requires to "merge" triples that express the same meaning in both datasets, but I couldn't find any.

The following query returns an empty result at the Yago [endpoint](http://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql) and only very few entries at the DBPedia [endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select ?s ?o
where {
    ?s owl:equivalentProperty ?o .
}
```

Comment: There is nothing manually created/curated, but there are some tools/research papers out there that generated such things automatically - by means of some threshold/cutoff indeed.

Comment: Can you name an example? I didn't find anything useful, yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools that automatically generated mappings between classes and properties of DBpedia and Yago. You can download some of these files here: 
[Yago to DBpedia linking](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/linking/)